# Querying a value from the QuadDraw Tool iniated by the user in liveMode in Maya

Tags: python, maya

I understand the command in Maya to create a quad draw point is
cmds.mtkQuadDrawPoint

but, what I am looking to do is store/return the value that is created when the user create a quad draw point in the quad draw tool.

So far it does not look like there is a lot of documentation about the commands from the modeling toolkit. I noticed that when the point is created the value appears in the console. Is it possible to get that value?